# smb browsing with Nautilus - how to cache results?

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba, smb, pcmanfm

When I use `Nautilus` (standard Ubuntu, all distributions up to 17.04), a network access to large smb shares is painfully slow. It takes not only seconds for the results to build (expected), but also going into a subdirectory and then back takes the same time.

This makes browsing the share very tedious.

I have noticed that the behaviour of `PCManFM` or `PCManFM-Qt` on LXQt / Lubuntu is different. The first access takes the same time, but afterwards, the results are cached and I can jump to subdirectories and back without delay. If I change something, I need to push <kbd>F5</kbd> to update the directory, but browsing is smooth. Overall, a much better browsing experience.

Is there a way to make `Nautilus` also cache the directories and behave like `PCManFM`? I am baffled that this isn't standard behaviour anyway.

Comment: did you find a solution to this in the meantime? I'm having the same issue on 18.04 (and earlier versions)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I just use PCManFM-Qt now with Lubuntu.